# find with $and - long time to complete

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm using MongoDb 3.4.

I have two collections in a database - lets call `coll1` and `coll2`. The two collections have two fields in common - say `field1` & `field2` and other distinct columns.

I need to create a new collection (say `coll3`) of documents with - all fields of `coll2` and with two fields - say `field3` and `field4` of `coll1` for the documents matching  `field1` values & `field2` values across `coll1` & `coll2`

**Reproducible example**

```
db.coll1.insert([
        { "field1": 321, "field2": "12",  "Car": "camry" },
        { "field1": 321, "field2": "13",  "Car": "camry" },
        { "field1": 323, "field2": "12",  "Car": "accord" },
        { "field1": 324, "field2": "15",  "Car": "Sunny" }
    ])

db.coll2.insert([
        { "field1": 321, "field2": "12",  "RegNo": "1122", "State": 'AZ' },
        { "field1": 321, "field2": "13",  "RegNo": "1123", "State": 'AZ' },
        { "field1": 323, "field2": "12",  "RegNo": "1124", "State": 'CA' }
    ])
```

**Required output** ( id not included for brevity)

```
[
        { "field1": 321, "field2": "12",  "Car": "camry",  "RegNo": "1122", "State": 'AZ' },
        { "field1": 321, "field2": "13",  "Car": "camry",  "RegNo": "1123", "State": 'AZ' },
        { "field1": 323, "field2": "12",  "Car": "accord",  "RegNo": "1124", "State": 'CA' }
]
```

So I do this like below

```
var results = db.coll2.find({}, {_id: 0}).toArray();
for( var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
   result = results[i];
    var doc = db.coll1.findOne({$and: [{field1: result["field1"]},
    {field2: result["field2"]}] }, {_id: 0});
    if(doc && doc["Car"]) {
        result["Car"] = doc["Car"]
        db.coll3.insertOne(result);
    }
}
```

This works, however, it takes a long time (many hours) to get this done with `coll1` with 500k documents and `coll2` with 50k documents. Why is it taking such a long time ? What can be done to make this faster ?

Comment: @chridam - sample docs aded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** you can achieve the same logic but more efficiently as you will be using MongoDB's aggregation framework which uses its native operators to compute the aggregates in a more efficient manner.

Consider running the below aggregate operation to get the desired result:

```
db.coll2.aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "coll1",
            "localField": "field1",
            "foreignField": "field1",
            "as": "coll1Docs"
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "coll1Docs": {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                    {
                        "$filter": {
                            "input": "$coll1Docs",
                            "as": "doc",
                            "cond": {  "$eq": [ "$field2", "$$doc.field2" ]  }                                        
                        }
                    },
                    0
                ]
            }
        } 
    },      
    { "$addFields": { "Car": "$coll1Docs.Car" } }
    { "$project": { "coll1Docs": 0 } },
    { "$out": "coll3" } 
])
```

Then run `db.coll3.findOne()` to confirm.

---

### Explanations

The first pipeline, **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)**, performs a left outer join to an unsharded collection in the same database to filter in documents from the "joined" collection for processing.

It provides an equality match between a field from the input documents with a field from the documents of the "joined" collection, which in this case is `coll2`. To each input document, the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** stage adds a new array field whose elements are the matching documents from the "joined" collection. In then passes these reshaped documents to the next stage.

Running the pipeline with just the first stage

```
db.coll2.aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "coll1",
            "localField": "field1",
            "foreignField": "field1",
            "as": "coll1Docs"
        }
    }
])
```

will yield

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b179a730c6c0da2c31a4de"),
    "field1" : 321.0,
    "field2" : "12",
    "RegNo" : "1122",
    "State" : "AZ",
    "coll1Docs" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58b179a730c6c0da2c31a4da"),
            "field1" : 321.0,
            "field2" : "12",
            "Car" : "camry"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58b179a730c6c0da2c31a4db"),
            "field1" : 321.0,
            "field2" : "13",
            "Car" : "camry"
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b179a730c6c0da2c31a4df"),
    "field1" : 321.0,
    "field2" : "13",
    "RegNo" : "1123",
    "State" : "AZ",
    "coll1Docs" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58b179a730c6c0da2c31a4da"),
            "field1" : 321.0,
            "field2" : "12",
            "Car" : "camry"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58b179a730c6c0da2c31a4db"),
            "field1" : 321.0,
            "field2" : "13",
            "Car" : "camry"
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b179a730c6c0da2c31a4e0"),
    "field1" : 323.0,
    "field2" : "12",
    "RegNo" : "1124",
    "State" : "CA",
    "coll1Docs" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58b179a730c6c0da2c31a4dc"),
            "field1" : 323.0,
            "field2" : "12",
            "Car" : "accord"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

The second pipeline step, **[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields)** allows you to add new fields to documents and outputs documents that contain all existing fields from the input documents and newly added fields.

It uses other operators to create a subdocument field that matches the other field, field2 on both collections. Because the above **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** operator produces a "left-join" on `coll1`, the resulting array produced will have all the documents from `coll1` that match on `field1`.

So, for example the second document with `field1 = 321` has the `coll1Docs` array with elements

```
"coll1Docs" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58b179a730c6c0da2c31a4da"),
        "field1" : 321.0,
        "field2" : "12",
        "Car" : "camry"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58b179a730c6c0da2c31a4db"),
        "field1" : 321.0,
        "field2" : "13",
        "Car" : "camry"
    }
]
```

needs to be filtered first to get a final flattened field

```
"coll1Docs" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b179a730c6c0da2c31a4da"),
    "field1" : 321.0,
    "field2" : "12",
    "Car" : "camry"
}
```

The inner expression which uses **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)**

```
"$filter": {
    "input": "$coll1Docs",
    "as": "doc",
    "cond": {  "$eq": [ "$field2", "$$doc.field2" ]  }                                        
}
```

does the filtering on `field2` and to produce the result

```
"coll1Docs" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58b179a730c6c0da2c31a4da"),
        "field1" : 321.0,
        "field2" : "12",
        "Car" : "camry"
    }
]
```

and the outer expression **[`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#exp._S_arrayElemAt)** will return the element in index position 0, which essentially flattens the above array to

```
"coll1Docs" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b179a730c6c0da2c31a4da"),
    "field1" : 321.0,
    "field2" : "12",
    "Car" : "camry"
}
```

Thus the pipeline

```
db.coll2.aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "coll1",
            "localField": "field1",
            "foreignField": "field1",
            "as": "coll1Docs"
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "coll1Docs": {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                    {
                        "$filter": {
                            "input": "$coll1Docs",
                            "as": "doc",
                            "cond": {  "$eq": [ "$field2", "$$doc.field2" ]  }                                        
                        }
                    },
                    0
                ]
            }
        } 
    }   
])
```

will yield

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b179a730c6c0da2c31a4de"),
    "field1" : 321.0,
    "field2" : "12",
    "RegNo" : "1122",
    "State" : "AZ",
    "coll1Docs" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58b179a730c6c0da2c31a4da"),
        "field1" : 321.0,
        "field2" : "12",
        "Car" : "camry"
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b179a730c6c0da2c31a4df"),
    "field1" : 321.0,
    "field2" : "13",
    "RegNo" : "1123",
    "State" : "AZ",
    "coll1Docs" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58b179a730c6c0da2c31a4db"),
        "field1" : 321.0,
        "field2" : "13",
        "Car" : "camry"
    }
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b179a730c6c0da2c31a4e0"),
    "field1" : 323.0,
    "field2" : "12",
    "RegNo" : "1124",
    "State" : "CA",
    "coll1Docs" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58b179a730c6c0da2c31a4dc"),
        "field1" : 323.0,
        "field2" : "12",
        "Car" : "accord"
    }
}
```

---

Now, the additional pipeline step with **[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields)** allows you to add a new field `Car` as:

```
db.coll2.aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "coll1",
            "localField": "field1",
            "foreignField": "field1",
            "as": "coll1Docs"
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "coll1Docs": {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                    {
                        "$filter": {
                            "input": "$coll1Docs",
                            "as": "doc",
                            "cond": {  "$eq": [ "$field2", "$$doc.field2" ]  }                                        
                        }
                    },
                    0
                ]
            }
        } 
    },  
    { "$addFields": { "Car": "$coll1Docs.Car" } }
])
```

which will produce

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b179a730c6c0da2c31a4de"),
    "field1" : 321.0,
    "field2" : "12",
    "RegNo" : "1122",
    "State" : "AZ",
    "coll1Docs" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58b179a730c6c0da2c31a4da"),
        "field1" : 321.0,
        "field2" : "12",
        "Car" : "camry"
    },
    "Car" : "camry"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b179a730c6c0da2c31a4df"),
    "field1" : 321.0,
    "field2" : "13",
    "RegNo" : "1123",
    "State" : "AZ",
    "coll1Docs" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58b179a730c6c0da2c31a4db"),
        "field1" : 321.0,
        "field2" : "13",
        "Car" : "camry"
    },
    "Car" : "camry"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b179a730c6c0da2c31a4e0"),
    "field1" : 323.0,
    "field2" : "12",
    "RegNo" : "1124",
    "State" : "CA",
    "coll1Docs" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58b179a730c6c0da2c31a4dc"),
        "field1" : 323.0,
        "field2" : "12",
        "Car" : "accord"
    },
    "Car" : "accord"
}
```

---

The preceding **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline step { "$project": { "coll1Docs": 0 } } will remove the `coll1Docs` field from the output:

```
db.coll2.aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "coll1",
            "localField": "field1",
            "foreignField": "field1",
            "as": "coll1Docs"
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "coll1Docs": {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                    {
                        "$filter": {
                            "input": "$coll1Docs",
                            "as": "doc",
                            "cond": {  "$eq": [ "$field2", "$$doc.field2" ]  }                                        
                        }
                    },
                    0
                ]
            }
        } 
    },  
    { "$addFields": { "Car": "$coll1Docs.Car" } }
    { "$project": { "coll1Docs": 0 } }          
])
```

to produce the reesult

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b179a730c6c0da2c31a4de"),
    "field1" : 321.0,
    "field2" : "12",
    "RegNo" : "1122",
    "State" : "AZ",
    "Car" : "camry"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b179a730c6c0da2c31a4df"),
    "field1" : 321.0,
    "field2" : "13",
    "RegNo" : "1123",
    "State" : "AZ",
    "Car" : "camry"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b179a730c6c0da2c31a4e0"),
    "field1" : 323.0,
    "field2" : "12",
    "RegNo" : "1124",
    "State" : "CA",
    "Car" : "accord"
}
```

The last pipeline stage **[`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out)** then writes the above results to the specified collection.

Comment: how to add one more field - say `field4` from `coll1` to the documents inserted to `coll3` ? Also what do `"$match": { "coll1Docs.0": { "$exists": true } }`, `"$addFields": {
            "field3": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$coll1Docs", 0] }` and `"$addFields": { "field3": "$field3.field3" }` achieve here ?

Comment: want to clarify couple of things about the question. One is that we want to match documents with same values for `field1` and `field2` - not `field1` values with `field2` values - I have updated the question.

Comment: Updated, hopefully this answers your query. Please check

Answer (score 1):

Logic in the question is asking for trouble. For each record fetched from first collection, the logic is doing a full collection scan every time in second collection.

Try

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: isn't something like `var doc = db.coll1.findOne({$and: [{field1: result["field1"]},
    {field2: result["field2"]}] }, {_id: 0});` a  common operation ?

Comment: The reason for logic to execute hours is because of the loop which is executing 500K times and each time a collection scan happens to find data from collection two.

Comment: what happened to constant time look-up etc. - aren't those implemented in MongoDb or am I understanding it incorrectly ? The reason I'm asking is in RDBMS the same operation would be lightning fast.